# div img src not displaying random image

Tags: php, image, random

I have code for a random image in the php section of my page

```
$imagesDir = 'images/eggs/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
```

it will display an image with this code

```
echo "<img src='$randomImage'>";
```

but when i try to do this in the body section of the page like this

```
<body>';
}
function template_body_above()
{
global $context, $settings, $options, $scripturl, $txt, $modSettings;
echo !empty($settings['forum_width']) ? '
<div id="wrapper" style="width: ' . $settings['forum_width'] . '">' : '', '
<div class="forest">
    <div id="egg1"></div>
</div>
<div id="header"><div class="frame">
    <div id="baloon1">
            <img src="egg.php"/> //tried including seperate php code
            <img src="<?php echo $randomImage ?>"> //php on same page
    </div>
```

I am showing for the image source ...%3C?php...
Any help on where I'm going wrong ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
  function template_body_above()
    {
        global $context, $settings, $options, $scripturl, $txt, $modSettings;
        echo  ( (!empty($settings['forum_width'])) ?  '<div id="wrapper" style="width: ' . $settings['forum_width'] . '">' : '')  .

                '
                <div class="forest">
                    <div id="egg1"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="header"><div class="frame">
                    <div id="baloon1">
                        <img src="' . $randomImage  . '">
                </div>
```

Comment: when i copy paste your code i get syntax error, unexpected 'template_body_above' (T_STRING)

Comment: @Flexxall did you add the closing bracket } ? I'm using the function now and it works on my server. I've added it in the code now

Comment: @Flexxall you can check that the function is correct and hasn't any syntax error (and test that it's working) on the following link: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e04131d4c1964e757e7c3a45f48e08590d20d398

Comment: the ending bracket for the function is much further down the page on my side. this is a smf forum page so theres alot of content

Comment: @Flexxall ok, I was guessing it and I didn't add it to the first answer for this reason. Anyway it's important there is one somewhere;)

Comment: yes but its still not working for me.. i can show the code for the whole page if you wish not sure if that would help or at least the whole function

Comment: Yes, send it to me and, please, copy also the exact error it's giving to you

Comment: not sure how to get you the code. I can not paste it in a response

Comment: Ok the error is in the line 188, as you should not close the string. In your full code, you close the string on the line 206. So I change the code in my answer now

Comment: This did remove the error, however the is still no image being displayed on the page

Comment: you should define $randomImage **inside** your function or declare it in the global line. In the function, at the moment, it's empty

Comment: Thank you, that worked. now to move on to the trickier stuff, im sure youll see more from me :)